# How to scroll horizontally fullscreen images in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, horizontalscrollview

I would to scroll full screen images in flutter but I've a problem when I use BoxDecoration within ListView

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/fav.JPG'),
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/fav.JPG'),
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Actually I receive a blank page. 
The idea is to do something like Netflix does by clicking on "Preview".

Thanks

Comment: The `DecorationImage` of a `Container` doesn't do anything to determine the `Container`'s size, so you're going to end up with a bunch of infinitesimally small widgets. Instead of `Container`, try using [`Image.asset`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html).

Comment: Sorry but it seems not be so helpful. Could you be a bit more clear please?

Comment: You are setting the background of the `Container` to be the image, but that doesn't affect the Container's size. As it stands, you have a container with no child and no specified width or height, so it is going to end up with a width and height of 0. However, if you display an image using the `Image` widget, the size of the widget will be dictated by the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're likely getting an undefined width on the List items. Since the ListView orientation is horizontal, you need to define the width for its List items. One approach would be to fetch the screen's width using either [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) or [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html), then set the width on the `Container`.